# Changing collection used for display in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, onclick, jsx

I have a react app which fetches products from json file, I have added two buttons on the top of the page so that each one of them will show the data from its json state.

so there is menu1 state and menu 2 and active list, ive made 2 functions as

```
  Active1() {
    this.setState({ activelist: !this.state.items });
  }

  Active2() {
    this.setState({ activelist: !this.state.items2 });
  }
```

and the buttons which toggle them are

```
   <button className="changebutton" onClick={this.Active1}>
            Menu 1
          </button>
          <button className="changebutton" onClick={this.Active2}>
            Menu2
          </button>
```

and that will show active list on click which is either menu1 and menu2, but it is not working.

file name 
**Itemlist.js**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/4jox1kq20x?fontsize=14  (you may want to click on the refresh button within sandbox)

Comment: some error on codesandbox, so what are you trying to achieve, after one api call success you need to call another is that's your question ?

Comment: I am trying to do it in a way where if i click in menu 1 it shows the normal data1 api 1 datapromise1, and when clicked on button 2 it shows data 2 api 2 datapromise2

Comment: so whats the issue, the problem is some error in the code box can you resolve the issue. It will be helpful to check the issue. And whats the issue right now ?

Comment: Create a third array (perhaps `activeList`.) Then simply call a function on the button click that copies `items` or `items2` into `activeList`. Finally, replace all references to `items` in the render method to `activeList`.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I have fixed the codebox

Comment: @RandyCasburn i have tried what you suggested, it didnt seem to work, maybe because i defined the initial stage as one of them? https://codesandbox.io/s/4jox1kq20x?fontsize=14

Comment: Just a few simple changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn6vp0qx4y?fontsize=14 Look for comments `// ADDED` and `// CHANGED`

Comment: By the way, I recommend you change the title to your question to read: Changing collection used for display in React. The current title and solution have nothing to do with each other as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a third array (perhaps `activeList`.) Then simply call a function on the button click that copies `items` or `items2` into `activeList`. Finally, replace all references to `items` in the render method to `activeList`. Here is the abbreviated code:

```
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  state = {
...
    items: [],
    items2: [],
    activelist: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    dataPromise.then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result,
          activelist: result
        });
      },
...
    );

    dataPromise2.then(
      result2 => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items2: result2
        });
      },
...
    );
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
...
    this.Active1 = this.Active1.bind(this); // ADDED
    this.Active2 = this.Active2.bind(this); // ADDED
  }
...
  Active1() {
    this.setState({ activelist: Object.assign({}, this.state.items) }); //CHANGED
  }

  Active2() {
    this.setState({ activelist: Object.assign({}, this.state.items2) }); //CHANGED
  }

  render() {
...
      return (
        <div>
          <button className="changebutton" onClick={this.Active1}>
            Menu 1
          </button>
          <button className="changebutton" onClick={this.Active2}>
            Menu2
          </button>
...
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn6vp0qx4y?fontsize=14